# Dynamic Routing In Javascript - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, routes, dynamic-routing

So in php you can do dynamic routing like

```
class Route
{
  public function homePage ()
  {
    echo 'You are on the home page'
  }

  public function otherPage ()
  {
    echo 'You are on some other page'
  }
}

class Route2
{
  public function homePage ()
  {
    echo 'You are on the home page'
  }

  public function otherPage ()
  {
    echo 'You are on some other page'
  }
}
// when you get the url like www.domain/route/other-page, with some regex operation you get out as string 'route' and 'other-page' from the route transform it to 'Route' and 'ohterPage' and fill them into the $controller and action variables and you just call:
$controller->$action();
// and it will call Route->otherPage() which will serve up the requested template
```

when you get the url like www.domain/route/other-page, with some regex operation you get out as string 'route' and 'other-page' from the route transform it to 'Route' and 'ohterPage' and fill them into the $controller and $action variables and you just call '$controller->$action();' and it will call Route->otherPage() which will serve up the requested template

it is nifty solution because then when you have lets say 40 different actions like serving up templates and various get and post request then you can handle it with adding just 5 routes but for this you need to reference the object and the method dynamically like above.... is there any way to achieve this in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: By "dynamic" do you mean the ability to instanciate objects by their class name ?

Comment: So by dynamic I mean that after you get the controller and the action out of the url so lets say this is the url: www.website.com/user/log-in and you extracted 'user' into a variable lets say called 'let controller' and 'log-in' into the variable called 'let action' and then you can instanciate the controller object by the value of the controller variable  and call the method on the controller by the value of the action variable... in php you can do it like 'let Controller = 'user'; let Action = 'logIn'; let controller = new Controller(); controller.action(); and this will call user.logIn();

Answer (score 0):

Use Express Js for this:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

Refer: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I meant dynamic routing what you show is static

Comment: How is your PHP version dynamic ? If you want to add a route you need to update the code that's not what I would call dynamic